# Changing hash value doesnt work

Tags: manifest, puppet

My hash is as follow:

```
$hash = {
  'somekey' => {
     online => true,
     date   => today
  }
}
```

I do some random check to change the value of the online key. If something's offline, I want to change the value to offline.

I tried the following code:

```
$::hash[somekey][online] = false
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Is there any way I can change the value of online? :(

Comment: Cannot reassign variable hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If at all possible, restructure your manifest.

In most programming languages, you will use constructs like

```
$variable = default-value
if ( condition ) {
    $variable = another-value
}
```

The following structure lends itself much better to Puppet's programming paradigm, however.

```
if ( condition ) {
    $variable = another-value
}
else {
    $variable = default-value
}
```

As for complexer hashes, you might get away with selector expressions.

```
$hash = {
  'somekey' => {
    'status' => $condition ? {
      'special-case' => 'offline',
      default        => 'online',
    'date'   => 'today'
  }
}
```

It's either that, or storing the dynamic value in a variable that is used in the declaration of the hash value.

Answer (score 1):

One of the tricky parts of puppet is that *everything is immutable*, including your hashes and other variables. That means that the only way to "modify" values is to save intermediate states to new variables.

For example, you might do this using `puppetlabs-stdlib`'s `merge` function:

```
$hash_original = {
  'somekey' => {
     online => true,
     date   => today
  }
}

$hash_updated = merge($hash_original, {'someotherkey' => 5})
```

This will create a hash with the two keys, and overwrite any keys present in both hashes. It will not do a "deep" merge, so if you need to modify more than one value down you will need to merge that level, then merge the higher level.